# Making sure OnPropertyChanged() is called on UI thread in MVVM WPF app

Tags: .net, wpf, multithreading, mvvm

In a WPF app that I'm writing using the MVVM pattern, I have a background process that doing it's thing, but need to get status updates from it out to the UI.

I'm using the MVVM pattern, so my ViewModel knows virtually nothing of the view (UI) that is presenting the model to the user.

Say I have the following method in my ViewModel:

```
public void backgroundWorker_ReportProgress(object sender, ReportProgressArgs e)
{
    this.Messages.Add(e.Message);
    OnPropertyChanged("Messages");
}
```

In my view, I have a ListBox bound to the Messages property (a `List<string>`) of the ViewModel.  `OnPropertyChanged` fulfills the role of the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface by calling a `PropertyChangedEventHandler`.

I need to ensure that `OnPropertyChanged` is called on the UI thread - how do I do this?  I've tried the following:

```
public Dispatcher Dispatcher { get; set; }
public MyViewModel()
{ 
    this.Dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
}
```

Then adding the following to the `OnPropertyChanged` method:

```
if (this.Dispatcher != Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher)
{
    this.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new ThreadStart(delegate
    {
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }));
    return;
}
```

but this did not work.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

WPF automatically marshals property changes to the UI thread. However, it does not marshal collection changes, so I suspect your adding a message is causing the failure.

You can marshal the add manually yourself (see example below), or use something like [this technique](http://kentb.blogspot.com/2008/01/cross-thread-collection-binding-in-wpf.html) I blogged about a while back.

Manually marshalling:

```
public void backgroundWorker_ReportProgress(object sender, ReportProgressArgs e)
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action<string>(AddMessage), e.Message);
    OnPropertyChanged("Messages");
}

private void AddMessage(string message)
{
    Dispatcher.VerifyAccess();
    Messages.Add(message);
}
```

Comment: That did it, with one other minor modification - I changed my List<string> to an ObservableCollction<string> and it works like a charm.  Thanks!

Comment: If 'Messages' is observable there's no need to call OnPropertyChanged() for it.

Answer (score 8):

I REALLY like Jeremy's answer:
[Dispatching In Silverlight](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jlikness/archive/2009/12/16/dispatching-in-silverlight.aspx)

Summary:

- Placing Dispatcher in ViewModel seems inelegant
- Creating an Action<Action> property, set it to just run the action in the VM constructor
- When using the VM from the V, set the Action property to invoke the Dispatcher

Comment: The original link is now broken. Here is a replacement from Wayback Machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20160402132636/http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/jlikness/dispatching-in-silverlight

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar scenario just this week (MVVM here too). I had a separate class doing its thing, reporting back status on an event handler. The event handler *was being called as expected, and I could see the results coming back right on time with Debug.WriteLine's*.

But with WPF, no matter what I did, the UI would not update until the process was complete. As soon as the process finished, the UI would update as expected. It was as if it was getting PropertyChanged, but waiting for the thread to complete before doing the UI updates all at once.

(Much to my dismay, the same code in Windows.Forms with a DoEvents and .Refresh() worked like a charm.)

So far, I've resolved this by starting the process on its own thread:

```
//hook up event handler
myProcess.MyEvent += new EventHandler<MyEventArgs>(MyEventHandler); 

//start it on a thread ...
ThreadStart threadStart = new ThreadStart(myProcess.Start);

Thread thread = new Thread(threadStart);

thread.Start();
```

and then in the event handler:

```
private void MyEventHandler(object sender, MyEventArgs e) { 
....
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(
                DispatcherPriority.Send,
                (DispatcherOperationCallback)(arg =>
                { 
         //do UI updating here ...
        }), null);
```

I'm not recommending this code, since I'm still trying to understand the WPF thread model, how Dispatcher works, and why in my case the UI wouldn't update until the process was complete even with event handler getting called as expected (by design?). But this has worked for me so far.

I found these two links helpful:

http://www.nbdtech.com/blog/archive/2007/08/01/Passing-Wpf-Objects-Between-Threads-With-Source-Code.aspx

http://srtsolutions.com/blogs/mikewoelmer/archive/2009/04/17/dealing-with-unhandled-exceptions-in-wpf.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I handle the `BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress` event outside of my `ViewModel` and pass the actual `BackgroundWorker` instance and the `ViewModel` into my class which defines the `async` method(s).

The `async` method then calls `bgWorker.ReportProgress` and passes a class which wraps a delegate as the `UserState` (as `object`). The delegate I write as an anonymous method.

In the event handler, I cast it from `object` back to the wrapper type and then invoke the delegate inside.

All this means that I can code UI changes directly from the code that's running asynchronously, but it just has this wrapping around it.

This explains it in more detail:

http://lukepuplett.blogspot.com/2009/05/updating-ui-from-asynchronous-ops.html

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an extension to the accepted answer but I did this with my event hander ...

```
using System.Threading;

private void Handler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (Thread.CurrentThread == this.Dispatcher.Thread)
    {
        //do stuff to this
    }
    else
    {
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(
            new Action<object, RoutedEventArgs>(Handler),
            sender,
            e);
    }
}
```