# ERROR in Threading using Timer and Data

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have implemented a delay in process after the user stops typing in the textbox

```
private System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);

public SearchItem(){
    timer.AutoReset = false;
    timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
}

private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e){
        bindingSource.DataSource = logic.GetData(StockCodeTextBox.Text);
}

private void StockCodeTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
        timer.Stop();
        timer.Start();

        if (StockCodeTextBox.Text.Equals("")){
            AllItemsGridView.ClearSelection();
            return;
        }
}
```

after the user stops typing, why am I getting this error?

> An exception of type **'System.InvalidOperationException'** occurred
>   in **System.Windows.Forms.dll** but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: **Cross-thread operation not valid:** Control
>   'AllItemsGridView' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was
>   created on.

Comment: You are using WPF right? And you are getting the error in the timer_Elapsed method?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF and cross thread operations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172229/wpf-and-cross-thread-operations)

Comment: yes. i am getting error in the timer_Elapsed method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your UI is updated on the WinForms UI Dispatcher thread, while your Timer executes on a background thread. So you can't update the UI from a thread which does not own it. One workaround is to use this extension to update your UI from background thread:

```
public static class ControlExtension
{
    public static void Do<TControl>(this TControl control, Action<TControl> action)
    where TControl : Control
    {
        if (control.InvokeRequired)
            control.Invoke(action, control);
        else
            action(control);
    }
}
```

Sample use:

```
this.Do(f=>{f.AllItemsGridView.ClearSelection();})
```

In your code:

```
private void StockCodeTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
    timer.Stop();
    timer.Start();

    this.Do(f=>{
        if (f.StockCodeTextBox.Text.Equals("")){
            f.AllItemsGridView.ClearSelection();
        }
    }
}

private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e){
    this.Do(f=>{ 
       f.bindingSource.DataSource = logic.GetData(f.StockCodeTextBox.Text);
    }
}
```

If you are free to choose a solution, consider rewriting your app with ReactiveUI and .Net 4.5.2. 
https://github.com/AdaptiveConsulting/ReactiveTrader

Comment: It would be nice if you add a reason why to execute the action on the UI-thread :) Reading the question indicates that the OP doesn't know anything regarding this issue ...

Comment: It's magic, @Rjmr ... :) Kidding aside, the extension simply extends any `Control` to have an extra method, wonderful isn't it? A `Form` derives from a `Control` so every form gets a new method, `Do`, which checks if the operation passed into it, the stuff in-between the curly brackets, should execute on the thread it arrived on, or if it should be redirected to the UI thread. Makes sense?

Comment: i think in his code it should be: `this.Do(f=>{
        bindingSource.DataSource = logic.GetData(StockCodeTextBox.Text);
    }`

Comment: thanks for letting me understand. But, i still have few questions on my mind. where would i put this line of code? `bindingSource.DataSource = logic.GetData(StockCodeTextBox.Text);`

Comment: Updated with a sample, but you should really, really consider ReactiveUI. Makes this whole thing soooo much simpler.

Comment: thank you so much guys for helping me with this one. if you have any suggestions on what topic/s should i study more, please comment it here. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `System.Windows.Forms`, you should use the Timer that comes with it so you don't have cross threading issues.

Instead of `System.Timers.Timer` use `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`.

Comment: that's not the problem. it's a problem of wpf updating the UI. He needs to use the Dispatcher in the `bindingSource.DataSource = logic.GetData(StockCodeTextBox.Text);` line i think.

Comment: @JensHorstmann Why do you assume WPF when the error message clearly says it's WinForms?

Comment: because i had this exception with the same problem in wpf - that's why.

Comment: i may be wrong with wpf, but it seems to be the same with Win Forms ;)

Comment: i am getting error in the timer_Elapsed method sir.