# ListView Data Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

I'm writing simple `WPF Application` and I wanted to use `ListView` to display `List` of items. My code is:

*`WPF.xaml`*

```
<ListView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,0,10,5" ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection.Elements}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementDescriptions}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

*`WPF.xaml.cs`*

```
public MyViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get { return DataContext; }
        set { DataContext = value; }
    }
```

*`MyViewModel.cs`*

```
public OwnedCollection Elements { get; set; }
```

*`OwnedCollection.cs`*

```
public List<ElementDescriptions> ElementDescriptions { get; set; }
```

I'm 100% sure, that communication between `View` and `ViewModel` is correct, because displaying simple message doesn't make me troubles. Am I doing right binding in `ListView`?

Comment: This line `ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection.Elements}` what happens when you change it to `ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}` also wondering if OwnedCollection should be ObservableCollection instead..

Comment: Nothing - the list is still empty. Still nothing.

Comment: I've changed List<ElementDescriptions> to ObservableCollection<ElementDescriptions>

Comment: did that help.. ? sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

A couple things:

First,

```
TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementDescriptions}"
```

doesn't make a lot of sense because ElementDescriptions is a collection.  If you want to loop through all the ElementDescriptions in your List you should really be binding the ItemSource of the ListView to ElementDescriptions then accessing some text property of the ElementDescriptions class:

```
<ListView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,0,10,5" ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection.ElementsElementDescriptions }">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementDescriptions.SomeTextField}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Second, are you using INotifyPropertyChanged so the view knows to update? More info on that here: [OnPropertyChanged with a List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807665/onpropertychanged-with-a-list)