# Notify WPF UI with WCF callback message

Tags: wpf, wcf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I have a problem updating my WPF UI while executing a WCF service which send messages to client after each action executed on service.
I use WSDualHttpBinding.
The same implementation works perfectly when I display a message box for each message came from the service. But this doesn't work on updating UI.

PS: I use MVVM pattern and Caliburn.micro
My implementation simplified:

1- Interfaces:

```
    public interface IMyContractCallback
{
    [OperationContract]
    void OnCallback();
}


 [ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IMyContractCallback))]
public interface IMyContract
{
    [OperationContract]
    void DoSomething();
}
```

2- Service:

```
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Reentrant)]
public class MyService : IMyContract
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        DoJob1();
        var callbackChannel = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IMyContractCallback>();
        callbackChannel.OnCallback();
        DoJob2();

    }
}
```

3- Client:

- Callback implementation:

public delegate void ClientNotifiedEventHandler(object sender, ClientNotifiedEventArgs e);

```
 public class ClientNotifiedEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
                private readonly string _message;
                public string Message { get { return _message; } }

                public ClientNotifiedEventArgs(string message)
                {
                    this._message = message;
                }
    }



    [CallbackBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Reentrant, UseSynchronizationContext = false)]
        public class MyCallbackClient : IMyContractCallback
        {
public event ClientNotifiedEventHandler ClientNotified;
            public void OnCallback()
            {
                 if (ClientNotified != null)
                        {
                            ClientNotified(this, new ClientNotifiedEventArgs(log));
                        }
            }
        }
```

1. ViewModel implementation:

   Public class MyViewModel
   {

   ```
       private string _message = "Loading..";

       public string MessageLog

       {
           get { return _message; }
           set
           {
               _message = value;
               NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => MessageLog);
           }
       }

       public void DoTheJob()
       {
           var callback = new DbLoaderCallback();
           callback.ClientNotified += Callback_ClientNotified;
           var context = new InstanceContext(callback);
           using (var serviceClient = new MyService(context))
           {
               serviceClient.DoSomething();
           }
       }

       private void Callback_ClientNotified(object sender, ClientNotifiedEventArgs e)
       {
           MessageLog += " \n";
           MessageLog += e.Message;

       }
   ```

   }

Here, when the execution come to callbackChannel.OnCallback(); (on MyService), It goes to client, on MyViewModel, when we come to NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => MessageLog);  it doesn't continue the execution. So DoJob2() did never executed.

Did any one see what's the problem exactly?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have `UseSynchronizationContext = false` specified for your callback, which means that all callbacks are called on a thread pool.
UI does not allow to update itself from any thread but dispatcher one. So, you need to marshal update of `MessageLog` property onto the dispatcher thread. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590590/making-sure-onpropertychanged-is-called-on-ui-thread-in-mvvm-wpf-app).